# Receive OSC Message on sending port

Tags: ruby, udp, ports, osc

I have an OSC server which returns data upon receiving a request message to the port used to send said request. Is there a way to find the port which was used to send the message (assigned by the os) and then open a listen channel on that port?

Answer (score 0):

Before sending your message from the client, just `bind` it.  For an automatically assigned port, use 0 as the port number.  Example:

```
require 'socket'
u = UDPSocket.new
u.bind('0.0.0.0', 0)
```

Now you can receive from the same port you send from.

Comment: That is useful information but I missed a key word in the original problem definition. I should of said it was an OSC server. I am currently using ruby-osc but I am open to changing libraries. I tried to adapt this but I cant seem to get it to work.